# Pass asnyc function to component

Tags: reactjs, mobx

How do I pass an async function to a component? Below the `next` function is an async function from my data store. I pass it `store.user.fetchUsers`. The method is available and the other properties work fine.

```
<InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={store.user.users.length}
      hasMore={store.user.hasMore}
      next={store.user.fetchUsers}
      loader={props.loader}
      endMessage={props.endMessage}
      scrollableTarget={document.getElementById('app')}
    >
      <div className="columns is-multiline">
        {snaps}
      </div>
    </InfiniteScroll>
```

But in my mobx store I have an async action:

```
 @action
  async fetchUsers () {
    let req;
    try {
      switch(this.genderFilter) {
        case 'male':
          req = await API.maleUsers(this.lastID())
          break
        case 'female':
          req = await API.femaleUsers(this.lastID())
          break
        default:
          req = await API.allUsers(this.lastID())
      }

      runInAction(() => {
        const users = req.body.users

        if (users && users.length <=0) {
          this.hasMore = false
        } else {
          this.addUsers(req.body.users)
        }

        this.state = 'done'
      })
    } catch (e) {
      runInAction(() => {
        this.state = 'error'
        this.hasMore = false
      })
    }
  }
```

How do I pass this to `next` so it can call it? Currently it's not being called.

Comment: add reference to `<InfiniteScroll />` component to see its API. in general calling async function does not differ from ordinary function call(but it always returns `Promise`). Have  you ensured it has been not called say with putting breakpoint in debugger?

Comment: Why did you delete your question?

Comment: The issue was Doctrine wasn't creating a `timestamp` column from my entities. It was creating a datetime column. As Doctrine doesn't support timestamp types I've recoded my API to convert timestamps to datatime. I only realised that after creating the sqlfiddle and inspected the code.

Comment: OK - Fair enough